# What are the standard ways of visualizing multivariate data with a high number of features?

Tags: machine-learning, data-visualization, scatterplot

I have a feature vector of 275 features which determine 1 of 10 classes.

What is the best way to visualize this data? I know I could do 275 scatter plots like this [image: multivariate scatter plot]

But that is less than ideal. Is there some more concise way to visualize the data, and get a feel for what correlations might exist visually?

Comment: Do you have any idea what might relationships might exist in these data, or what you might want to look at? Or are you completely new & exploring the possibilities for the first time ever?

Comment: @gung The latter

Comment: Being someone who works day to day with high dimensional data, I can tell you that there will only be about 20-30 variables that you truly care about for your needs. In industry, there are teams looking at the same data sets you are and they may care about 20-30 other variables that you don't. However, it seems you're new to your data and so my suggestion is to look at each individual one first before making assumptions about relationships.